# Android executes perfectly but doesn't display anything

Tags: android, json, parsing

I was trying to parse a json object with the help of a tutorial (this bundle http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Lr37suTPpg). I followed step by step the instructions and I managed to get the example that was given to work. But when I modified the example to work with my own json object, while there was no error, the emulator displayed nothing but a blank screen.

Keep in mind that my json object is anonymous (see the link below) unlike the oneof the example. I've made some modifications in the code for that matter but I am not really sure about them. Anyway I haven't been able to identify the cause of the problem so I would like to ask for your help. Below is my code (3 java files and 2 xml) and under that is the code of the example which works (also 3 java and 2 xml obviously).

**Sights.java (a.k.a. MainActivity.java / Also here is the link of the json object)**

```
package com.example.thodoras.jsontutorialtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Sights extends Activity {

 ListView list;
SightsAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HelperSights> sightsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sights);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    sightsList = new ArrayList<HelperSights>();

    new SightsAsyncTask().execute("http://www.escapeguide.gr/en/rest/views/mobile_listings.json?display_id=sights_service");
}

public class SightsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {


        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    HelperSights sights = new HelperSights();

                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);


                    sights.setImage(obj.getString("cover image"));
                    sights.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                    sights.setLocation(obj.getString("location"));

                    sightsList.add(sights);
                }

                return true;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result == false) {
            //something
        } else {
            SightsAdapter adapter = new SightsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, sightsList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}

}

package com.example.thodoras.jsontutorialtest;
```

**HelperSights.java (contains getters setters)**

```
public class HelperSights {

private String image;
private String title;
private String location;

public HelperSights(){

}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
}
```

**SightsAdapter.java**

package com.example.thodoras.jsontutorialtest;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SightsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HelperSights> {

ArrayList<HelperSights> ArrayListSights;
int Resource;
Context context;
LayoutInflater vi;

public SightsAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<HelperSights> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    ArrayListSights = objects;
    Resource = resource;
    this.context = context;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.sImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sImage);
        holder.sTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sTitle);
        holder.sLocation = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sLocation);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    new DownloadImageTask(holder.sImage)
    .execute(ArrayListSights.get(position).getImage());
    holder.sTitle.setText(ArrayListSights.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.sLocation.setText(ArrayListSights.get(position).getLocation());

    return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolder{

    public ImageView sImage;
    public TextView sTitle;
    public TextView sLocation;

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
}
```

**activity_sights.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"    android:background="#F1F1F1"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/sImage"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sTitle"
            android:text="Yo
            "/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sLocation"
            android:text="Man"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Below are the the files of the successful example that might help you compare.

**MainActivity.java (contains the link of the json object)**

```
package com.example.thodoras.jsontutorail;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
ActorsAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();

    new    ActorAsyncTask()
.execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");
}

public class ActorAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {


        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("actors");

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    JSONObject jRealObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    actor.setName(jRealObject.getString("name"));
                    actor.setDescription(jRealObject.getString("description"));
                    actor.setDob(jRealObject.getString("dob"));
                    actor.setCountry(jRealObject.getString("country"));
                    actor.setHeight(jRealObject.getString("height"));
                    actor.setSpouse(jRealObject.getString("spouse"));
                    actor.setChildren(jRealObject.getString("children"));
                    actor.setImage(jRealObject.getString("image"));

                    actorsList.add(actor);

                }

                return true;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result == false){
            finish();
        } else {
            ActorsAdapter adapter = new ActorsAdapter
            (getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row, actorsList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Actors.java (similar to HelperSights.java)**

```
package com.example.thodoras.jsontutorail;



public class Actors {

private String name;
private String description;
private String dob;
private String country;
private String height;
private String spouse;
private String children;
private String image;

public Actors(){

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public String getSpouse() {
    return spouse;
}

public void setSpouse(String spouse) {
    this.spouse = spouse;
}

public String getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(String children) {
    this.children = children;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

**ActorsAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.thodoras.jsontutorail;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ActorsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {

ArrayList<Actors> ArrayListActors;
int Resource;
Context context;
LayoutInflater vi;

public ActorsAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    ArrayListActors = objects;
    Resource = resource;
    this.context = context;

    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.tvDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptionn);
        holder.tvDob = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateOfBirth);
        holder.tvCountry = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
        holder.tvHeight = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
        holder.tvSpouse = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSpouse);
        holder.tvChildren = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvChildren);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageView)
    .execute(ArrayListActors.get(position).getImage());
    holder.tvName.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvDescription.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.tvDob.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getDob());
    holder.tvCountry.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getCountry());
    holder.tvHeight.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getHeight());
    holder.tvSpouse.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getSpouse());
    holder.tvChildren.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getChildren());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{

    public TextView tvName;
    public TextView tvDescription;
    public TextView tvDob;
    public TextView tvCountry;
    public TextView tvHeight;
    public TextView tvSpouse;
    public TextView tvChildren;
    public ImageView imageView;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"    android:background="#F1F1F1"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**row-xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="4dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tom Cruise"
            android:textColor="#166CED"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDateOfBirth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:text="Date of Birth: July 3, 1962" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Height: 1.80 m"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#D64530"
            android:text="United States" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescriptionn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#009A57"
    android:text="Description" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSpouse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#166CED"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Spouse: Katie Holmes" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvChildren"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#166CED"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Children: Suri Cruise, Isabella Jane Cruise, Connor Cruise" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In original example web service is built in a different way.

You should use `HttpGet` in your `SightsAsyncTask` to request data from the server.

Moreover, I would suggest you using [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead of `DefaultHttpClient`.
The request to get data would be like:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.escapeguide.gr/en/rest/views/mobile_listings.json?display_id=sights_service");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int status = connection.getResponseCode();
if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    ByteArrayBuffer buffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(4096);
    int byteCount = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
    do buffer.append(bytes, 0, byteCount); while ((byteCount = is.read(bytes)) != -1);
}
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(new String(buffer));
```

Note: the above implementation reads input stream to a byte array. However, you can read it to String or StringBuilder since ContentType of your server response is text (JSON). Reading to byte array could be used as a universal solution for requests which return data in different formats (like PDF file)

Comment: Thank you very much! HttpGet instead of HttpPost was enough. When I have more time I will carefully look into the rest of your suggestion. Right now, to be honest I don't fully understand where should I implement the code you have given and what should I remove in its place.